# Best SEO Plugin Recommendation

Tags: ee2, plugin, seo, seo-lite

I need an SEO plugin that is similar to SEO lite, https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/seolite. Basically something that is simple, with global settings, and entry overrides. I like this plugin, but its main issue is that it cannot deal with images. The fact that EE cannot have multiple field groups per channel also basically makes it so you always have to use a plugin for this feature. I mostly just maintain EE websites and don't do new development with EE. Some suggestions from people who still develop heavily with EE would be great. This site is EE 2.9.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use custom fields? That way you have complete control, per channel, and only the channels that need this data...

Comment: Does not really work well. I have many channels that represent pages. So I would have to add the same seo image field to lots of channels and have them all have different short names for the same purpose. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out SEO Lite's extra tags functionality?

http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite/extra-tags

You would still need to create the fields for images etc. in the different channel field groups, but at least you've only got one header code (the SEO Lite template)

Comment: I would say that gets me half way. It still does not solve my problem of wanting a override seo image on the channels that I want. Thank you a ton for your input by the way.

Comment: Hi David .. not sure what you mean by "override seo image on the channels that I want". You could have default info for the image in the template, and then override on the channels which have fields for the image ..?